# Use function as class method

Tags: class, function, scala, implicit-conversion

I am trying to figure out how to use a function as a member of a class, but can not figure out the correct syntax. I get an compilation error:

```
test.scala:11: error: missing arguments for method extra in class RichString;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
println("This is".extra);
```

How would I keep `extra` as a function defined outside of the class `RichString` and use it to extend the `String` class?

Thanks.

test.scala:

```scala
class RichString(a: String) {
  def extra(a: String):String
}

def extra(a: String): String = {
  return a+" Extra!";
}

implicit def string2Rich(s: String) = new RichString(s);

println("This is".extra);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
scala> class RichString(a: String) {
     |   def extra = a + "extra"
     | }
defined class RichString

scala> implicit def enrichString(s: String) = new RichString(s)
enrichString: (s: String)RichString

scala> println("this is".extra)
this isextra
```

Comment: I was hoping to keep the logic of how `extra` operates outside of the class `RichString`. In my example, `extra`'s logic is defined outside of the class. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: @Jeremiah But any method has to be defined in a class or object somewhere.

Comment: @matthew-farwell I was assuming it was possible to declare a function in a class (like C++), but keep the definition of the function outside of the class... I was mistaken?

Comment: @Jeremiah yes, all methods must be defined within a class or object.